# How to find out the name of the constraint CHECK of a field in the MSAccess database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ddl

I am implementing a solution for updating the schema of *MSAccess* databases on customer site and  I am using *DataWeigher* to generate the update script.

My small console application wtitten in C# executes the generated script.

And now I want to change some existing validation rule of a field.

To change an existing validation rule I would use following commandos:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP CONSTRAINT <nameOfConstraint>
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT <nameOfConstraint> CHECK(myFiled<42)
```

The original validation rule was created manually (via *MSAccess*) and I do not know what name was given to this constraint by *MSAccess*.

How could I find out what the nameOfConstraint should be provide to the DDL commando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/OutputConstraintProperties.htm), you can use `DataTable.Constraints[Index].ConstraintName` to get the name(s) and hopefully other properties to identify which constraint is to be changed.

Comment: Many thanks, especially for the link, I have not known this site!